# NODEJS - connection to database ECONNREFUSED when using documents.write()

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I'm currently studying nodejs and marklogic, I'm running a sample code but I cannot make it work I'm getting econnrefused whenever I run the code.,

Here is my code,

my-connection.js

```
module.exports = {
    connInfo: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8008,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password'
    }
};
```

sample.js

```
const marklogic = require('marklogic');
const my = require('./my-connection.js');
const db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);
const documents = [
{ uri: '/gs/aardvark.json',
 content: {
  name: 'aardvark',
  kind: 'mammal',
  desc: 'The aardvark is a medium-sized burrowing, nocturnal mammal.'
 }
},
{ uri: '/gs/bluebird.json',
 content: {
  name: 'bluebird',
  kind: 'bird',
  desc: 'The bluebird is a medium-sized, mostly insectivorous bird.'
 }
},
{ uri: '/gs/cobra.json',
  content: {
   name: 'cobra',
   kind: 'mammal',
   desc: 'The cobra is a venomous, hooded snake of the family Elapidae.'
  }
  },
];

db.documents.write(documents).result(
function(response) {
 console.log('Loaded the following documents:');
 response.documents.forEach( function(document) {
  console.log(' ' + document.uri);
 });
},
function(error) {
 console.log('error here');
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
}
);
```

I'm running it by typing `node sample.js` I'm using marklogic for the database, can someone help me identify the problem here,

I get ECONNREFUSED upon running the app, thank you!

Comment: make sure that you've started your db

Comment: how do i do that? thank you, it was not written on the tutorial I'm reading,

Comment: im currently configuring marklogic, it wasnt as easy as i thought it would be,

Comment: @devansvd - There's no MongoDB server here ....

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNREFUSED` indicates no TCP listener process is running behind `localhost:8008`. That could mean MarkLogic is not running on your localhost, or it has no app-server configured at port 8008.

Check if http://localhost:8001 works on your machine, and brings up the MarkLogic Admin UI. If so, check the app-servers to see if you actually have one configured for 8008.

HTH!